# How to filter an array using NSPredicate in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, nspredicate

I have an arraycontaining several dictionaries.

```
{
   DisplayName?:"Name of the employee"
   Age:28
   Department:"Dept 2"
}
```

I just converted my objective-c code into swift and trying to filter like this.

```
let exists = NSPredicate(format: "DisplayName2 CONTAINS[cd] \(searchText!)")
    let aList: Array<Any> = arrayDirectory.filter { exists.evaluate(with: $0) }
    if(aList.count>0)
    {
        arrayDirectory=aList
        facesCarousel.reloadData()
    }
```

But I am always getting the `aList` count as 0. It seems like not filtering my array. How can I write proper `NSPredicate`in swift 3 and filter my array using it.

Comment: let filteredArray = (arrayofDictionary as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(speciesPredicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native Swift equivalent to the ObjC code is

```
let filteredArray = arrayDirectory.filter { ($0["displayName2"] as! String).range(of: searchText!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
```

assuming `arrayDirectory` is a native Swift `Array`. It considers also the `case insensitive` and `diacritic insensitive` parameters.

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for the answer. But I have a little problem. Sometimes when I type morethan 3 letters, it gives me a wrong selection. But it always correct if I type 3 letters. Any solution to overcome this?

Comment: Actually the solution is independent from the length of the search string.

Comment: @vadian How to do `BEGINSWITH` using filter?

Comment: If case sensitivity doesn't matter `.hasPrefix` (`($0["displayName2"] as! String).hasPrefix()`), if it does matter you have to check if the `startIndex` of the string is the `lowerBound` of the` range`.

Answer (score 6):

To make this filter in Swift doesn't require `NSPredicate` at all.

```
let array = arrayDirectory.filter {
    guard let name = $0["DisplayName"] as? String else {
        return false
    }
    return name.contains(searchText) 
}
```

That should be all you need.

### EDIT

Updated to match your dictionary. I think this is what you're doing.

Ideally, you shouldn't be using a standard `Dictionary` as a working object. Convert your array of dictionaries to an array of Structs. That way you don't need to stringly type your code or unwrap properties that aren't really optional.

### Workaround for working with an `[Any]` array...

Because you have defined your array as `[Any]` (don't do this) you will need to convert the object to a dictionary first.

```
let array = arrayDirectory.filter {
    guard let dictionary = $0 as? [String: Any],
        let name = dictionary["DisplayName"] as? String else {
        return false
    }
    return name.contains(searchText) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much,, can you pls tell me whats the $0 indicates? and let say my Display name is "Firstname lastname" can I search this by "lastname" as well?

Comment: @user1960169 the filter function takes a single parameter in the closure. You can either use the syntax `{ object in ... }` and work with `object` or skip that and use `$0` instead. I'd suggest reading the free Swift books from Apple. They explain all of this.

Comment: @user1960169 Vadian's answer is probably more suitable as it also address the case insensitive search which might be what you need. (That's what the `[cd]` in your original code does.

Comment: hello, Im getting an error near the $0 $0["DisplayName"] as? String else

Comment: @user1960169 what error? Without seeing the error I can't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148869/discussion-between-user1960169-and-fogmeister).

Comment: im getting an eror like Type Any has no subscript members
this comes at the $0

Comment: @user1960169 that's because you're defining your array of dictionaries as `[Any]`. You shouldn't be using `Any` at all. Define it as `[[String: Any]]` for now. But, like I said, you should be converting the dictionaries to structs to avoid this.

Comment: Do you mean I need to convert my arrayDirectory  into structs? Before this line?

Comment: @user1960169 read the Swift book. It will explain a lot of things that will help you. At the moment you appear to be "hacking". A little reading will save you a hell of a lot of time.

Comment: so im confused and still dont have a clear idea how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @user1960169 define the array as `[[String: Any]]`. Somewhere in your code you have something like `var arrayDirectory: [Any] = ...`. Change this to `var arrayDirectory: [[String: Any]] = ...`

Answer (score 4):

you can try

```
self.arrayDirectory.filter({(($0["Age"] as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))!})
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code my code will help you

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "DisplayName2 contains[c] %@", textField.text!)
 let arr : NSArray = arrayDirectory.filtered(using: predicate) as NSArray
 if arr.count > 0
 {
    arrayDirectory=arr
    facesCarousel.reloadData()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its worked fine in my side I hope this code will be help you

I have an array that array containing several dictionaries. Structure will be like this

```
 [
 {
  DisplayName:"Name of the employee1"
  Age:28
  Department:"Dept 2"
 }
 ]
```

In above array i am filtering with displayName key using apple search controller with help of predicate method

```
  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

    if (searchController.searchBar.text?.characters.count)! > 0 {
        guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text, searchText != "" else {
            return
        }

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "DisplayName CONTAINS[C] %@", searchText)

        usersDataFromResponse = (filteredArray as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)

        print ("array = \(usersDataFromResponse)")

        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }


}
```