# How to filter an array of objects using NSPredicate?

Tags: swift, nspredicate

How can I filter an array of objects using `NSPredicate`?

I have found a similar question with answer here ([How to filter an array using NSPredicate in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029770/how-to-filter-an-array-using-nspredicate-in-swift-3/45029904#45029904)) But it is not using `NSPredicate`.

```
class Person {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
}

let alice = Person(firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Smith", age: 24)
let bob = Person(firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Jones", age: 27)
let charlie = Person(firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Smith", age: 33)
let quentin = Person(firstName: "Quentin", lastName: "Alberts", age: 31)
let people = [alice, bob, charlie, quentin]

let bobPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = 'Bob'")
let smithPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "lastName = %@", "Smith")
let thirtiesPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "age >= 30")
```

I have tried using this. But it gives me an execution error.

`let filteredBob = (people as NSArray).filtered(using: bobPredicate)`

Comment: You should use Swift native methods. Why do you need to use a NSArray predicate? `people.filter {$0.firstName == "Bob"}`

Comment: Because I am learning to use NSPredicate.

Comment: Btw you should use structures most of the time `struct Person {
    let firstName, lastName: String
    let age: Int
}`
`extension Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { firstName + " " + lastName }
}`

Comment: People say NSPredicate plays along really well with Regular Expression.  Do you think NSPredicate is deprecated and it is not required to work with Regex?

Comment: I have used regex many times and never needed to learn NSPredicate

Comment: Alright. That's great to hear.

Comment: `NSPredicate` can be quite useful when using CoreData and other Database no?

Comment: @Larme Yes, I agree with you. It is also another reason I am learning to use `NSPredicate`.

Comment: You should have put the error speaking about KVC which leads to NSObject & @objc (if hennes answer works, but it should so).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code `Person` is a pure Swift class. `NSPredicate` relies on the Objective-C runtime though so in order to use it, you have to make the properties you filter on available to Objective-C, e.g.

```
class Person: NSObject {
    @objc let firstName: String
    ...
```

Afterwards, you can use the predicate `NSPredicate(format: "firstName = 'Bob'")` on an array of `Person` objects.